# Web service - REST to SOAP architecture

Tags: .net, web-services, rest, soap

I work on a .NET project where I have a web service (ASP.NET project) with a REST architecture. The user can call three functions with the help of IIS on these URLs:

```
127.0.0.1:8080/api/function1/
127.0.0.1:8080/api/function2/
127.0.0.1:8080/api/function3/
```

The web service contains these functions controllers.

I was asked to transform theses functions to a SOAP version. I know very little about web programming and I'm not sure how to do that or where I can start looking. Would you have any leads ?

Thx

Comment: Show us your web.config and some method definition. It is possible you will be able to just configure the service.

Comment: What part of the web.config can help ?
Concerning the medhods, there are one controller for each functions and the controller contains just one method "Get". For example, one function return a message base on the messageId so it's public string Get(int messageId)

Comment: It seems like you are not using wcf, or asmx service. Show us code related to service.

Comment: Yes indeed i'm not using wcf, that's what I was wondering : do I need to create a new project in wcf ?

Comment: It would be the best way, how to handle this task, from my point of view (if you really need SOAP).

Answer (score 0):

Use web api  they are based on content based routing. They will cater both rest as well as soap based calls